# Display textbox when others option when other option is selected and save it to database in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to save the roadname in to my database but everytime it shows column roadname cannot be null. If I remove the other option then it works fine. i will attach my controller

```js
function Checkroad(val) {
  var element = document.getElementById('roadname');
  if (element == 'others')
    element.style.display = 'block';
  else
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<select name="roadname" id="roadname" class="custom-select mb-3 " onchange="Checkroad(this.value);">
  <option selected disabled>Select a roadname</option>
  <option value="National Highway No. 4 Dahisarmori to Dandphata" </option>
  <option value="National Highway No. 548 Kalamboli Circle to D Point" </option>
  <option value="National Highway No. 348" </option>
  <option value="National Highway No. 66" </option>
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="roadname" id="roadname" style="display: none;">
```

**Controller**

```
$accident = new Accident();
            $accident->branch_id = $request->input('branch');
        $accident->roadname = $request->input('roadname');
        $accident->date = $request->input('dtb_yr');
        $accident->time = $request->input('appt');      
        $accident->no_of_vehicle = $request->input('noofvehicle');
        $accident->injured = $request->input('injured');
        $accident->death = $request->input('death');
        $accident->hit_and_run = $request->input('hitandrun');
        $accident->construction = $request->input('construction');
        $accident->casereg = $request->input('caseregister');
        $accident->road_maintain = $request->input('road_maintain');
        $accident->IPC_MVAct_Sections = $request->input('ipmvc');
        $accident->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert the text between the option tags.

Change this:

```
<option value="National Highway No. 4 Dahisarmori to Dandphata"</option>
```

to:

```
<option value="1">National Highway No. 4 Dahisarmori to Dandphata</option>
```

(or leave the value the same)

In the js function you should check the value of the element and not the element itself.

Change this:

```
if(element=='others')
```

to:

```
if(element.value == 'others')
```

```html
<script>
    function Checkroad() {
        let select = document.getElementById('select');
        let road = document.getElementById('roadname');
        if(select.value === "others")
            road.style.display='block';
        else  
            road.style.display='none';
     }
</script>

<select name="roadname" id="select" class="custom-select mb-3 " onchange="Checkroad()">
    <option selected disabled>Select a roadname</option>
    <option value="National Highway No. 4 Dahisarmori to Dandphata">National Highway No. 4 Dahisarmori to Dandphata</option>
    <option value="National Highway No. 548 Kalamboli Circle to D Point">National Highway No. 548 Kalamboli Circle to D Point</option>
    <option value="National Highway No. 348">National Highway No. 348"</option>
    <option value="National Highway No. 66">National Highway No. 66</option>
    <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="roadname" id="roadname" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: Yeah but then in database the value will be saved as 1

Comment: ok so change the value to whatever your need, but don't remove the text between the tags.

Comment: Yeah did but still nothing is happening

Comment: It's working for me, I've added a code snippet.

Comment: where is it displaying the text box

Answer (score 2):

Based on class names, it looks like you're using Boostrap.

1. You have a syntax error, you did not property close your opening `<option>` tags.
2. I would avoid reusing `id` and `name` attributes, give each form item unique identifiers.
3. Since you are using Boostrap, might as well use jQuery's `$.fn.show()` and `$.fn.hide()` functions. You can simplify this by using `$.fn.toggle(boolean)`.
4. I reorganized the inputs by wrapping them within a `<form>` and Boostrap `<div class="container">`.
5. Lastly, use triple-equals (`===`) to compare type and value.

```js
function checkRoad(value) {
  $('input[name="other-road-name"]').toggle(value === 'other');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center">
  <form name="road-name-form">
    <div class="mb-2 row">
      <label for="road-name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Road Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control" id="road-name" name="road-name" onchange="checkRoad(this.value);">
          <option selected disabled>Select a road name</option>
          <option value="National Highway No. 4 Dahisarmori to Dandphata">
            National Highway No. 4 Dahisarmori to Dandphata
          </option>
          <option value="National Highway No. 548 Kalamboli Circle to D Point">
            National Highway No. 548 Kalamboli Circle to D Point
          </option>
          <option value="National Highway No. 348">
            National Highway No. 348
          </option>
          <option value="National Highway No. 66">
            National Highway No. 66
          </option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2 row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="other-road-name" name="other-road-name" placeholder="Other road name..." style="display:none" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `onchange` listener on the `<select>` and attach a `change` listener via jQuery:

```js
$('#road-name').on('change', function() {
  $('#other-road-name').toggle($(this).val() === 'other');
});
```